# Deleting a partition on dual boot

Tags: windows, multi-boot

I have split my C:\ physical disk into 3 seperate partitions: C, H, and K.

C has my original OS and is the active partition, H has another OS (dual boot), and K has song files.

I want to keep the other OS (Windows Server) and when I am in this OS, I can't delete C ("Windows cannot format this partition").

What is the best way for me to get rid of C, keep all the songs intact, and the Server OS partition, so I replace C with another OS, and then get rid of the original Windows Server OS (So revert the dual boot to a single boot).

Answer (score 1):

The partition can't be removed when it is mounted. Try removing the drive letter (in Administrative Tools/Disk Management), and then remove the partition. System partitions (and other partitions that are in use) can't be removed, so you obviously have to boot from the OS in H:.

Comment: Back up songs on the K partition to an external source (good idea anyway, if you are messing with the drive that houses these files).  Then back up all your valuable data elsewhere.  If you have the Windows Server boot disc, the cleanest way to do all this would be to start from scratch and reformat the entire disc and install Windows Server on the front of the drive.  This also will allow you to create new partitions...

This forum had some interesting ideas: 

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/17224-Can-Windows-7-be-run-on-other-than-quot-C-quot-drive

Answer (score 1):

Even though you boot from the H partition and aren't "in" your C partition, your C partition may still be "mounted", meaning it is still "in use".  If, after booting from your H partition, you can see your C drive and the files therein, then your C partition is mounted and you'll have to unmount it as described in a previous answer before you can delete it.  If you are unable to unmount it, then some program may be "in" your C drive or using a file in your C drive.

Booting off of an ubuntu live CD and using gparted should work well if you're comfortable with that route.

Of course, make sure you have a backup of everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can't format a partition you're currently in. You're going to have to go into windows server to format your C partition, afterwards depending on how you set up your boot system you might have to repair your boot.

Good Luck,
Kravlin

Comment: I'm actually IN windows server and formatting c, which is where Windows 7, the original OS that came with the PC, sits. I get the error above when I try to do this. I only attempt to format an OS partition when I'm not in that OS.

Comment: hm... have you tried using something off of a live cd like the ubuntu cd? (gparted is really useful). If that doesn't work then at least we've ruled out it being something weird with windows and know it's more to do with your drive.